# Laravel 8 rate limiter not working for routes

Tags: php, laravel, throttling, laravel-8, rate-limiting

In the web.php routes, I have the following:

```
Route::middleware('throttle:3,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/about', function () {
        return "About Info";
    });
});
```

The Laravel Framework is 8.19.0.

Ideally, when someone hits the page more than 3 times in 1 minute, laravel should give 429 Too Many Attempts Response. But it does not. I am not getting the 429 response after 3 times.

How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried configuring your rate limiting [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#defining-rate-limiters)?

Comment: You may need to include a rate limiter in the `configureRateLimiting()` function in `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`.

Comment: Yes tried adding in  RouteServiceProvider.php ```RateLimiter::for('requestslimit', function (Request $request) {return Limit::perMinute(3);});``` and in routes added ```middleware('throttle:requestslimit')```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-8/episodes/9 Please go through this video tutorial

Comment: Hmm, you may be able to see if the rate limiting middleware is being applied in telescope if you have it installed on your project.

Answer (score 21):

Since **Laravel 8** you can configure rate limits in the method `configureRateLimiting()` of the `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider` .

For example:

```
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}
```

Should you have updated from Laravel 7 do not forget to add the call to the method in the `boot()` method of the `RouteServiceProvider`. Otherwise the limits will not be applied.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    parent::boot();
}
```

See also documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#rate-limiting
and Laracasts video: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-8/episodes/9

Comment: The laracasts video was very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Very useful to have mentioned the Laravel 7 upgrade bit!

Answer (score 5):

go to the `.env` file and check your cache driver if `CACHE_DRIVER=none`, set a cache driver.
Laravel support Supported: "apc", "array", "database", "file",
"memcached", "redis", "dynamodb"

Comment: This was the tidbit I had overseen! Everything was working perfectly, my rate-limiter was just not counting the tries.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

`app/Http/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

The default `configureRateLimiting()` method is already there.

**Approach 2**

`routes/api.php`

```
Route::post('/send-otp', 'UtilityController@sendOtp')->middleware(['throttle:5,1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the issue. In the config/cache.php, the default was set to "null". I changed to "database". Now, this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 8 i had implemented this in this way, its easy to use :

in `RouteServiceProvider.php` just add  :

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;


    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            $key = 'login.' . $request->input('username') . '.' . $request->ip();
            $max = 5;  //attempts
            $decay = 120; // 120 seconds/2 minute for suspending 

            if (RateLimiter::tooManyAttempts($key, $max)) {
                return response()->json(['message' => __("messages.login.throttle.suspension")], Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
            } else {
                RateLimiter::hit($key, $decay);
            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the provider files that do not correspond to the current version of Laravel were replaced, the solution is to compress the entire project folder if it is being uploaded to the server and if the problem is on the local computer, restore the project with a new installation